# With a WCF Windows Service that is deployed, only a small subset of endpoints give a HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: windows, wcf, deployment, service

I have a solution containing about 20 WCF endpoints where each endpoint shares one of two configurations for bindings and behaviors.  The two different configuration I have is so I can either do a custom username/password authentication or do a certificate authentication.  All of my endpoints specify a specific base address.  If I start my project in debug mode, and I try to hit each of these services I get the page that contains a link to the WSDL and instructions to use SVCUti.

Now if I build out an installer for this WCF solution and install it out to a machine only about 3/4 of my services will show this test page.  Some of the services, when I try to go to the base address, give me a HTTP Bad Request 400 error.  These endpoints use the same configuration as endpoints that do work.  I'm stuck as to what types of things I can do to debug this issue.  Any advice on what this could be would be helpful.

Comment: Just to be clear: The HTTP 400 occurs when you navigate to the `.svc` URL in the browser, or when you actually try to invoke an operation?

Comment: Navigate to the .svc in the URL (even though these particular services do not have a .svc file associated with them).  An example address is: http://MACHINENAME:12903/Our/Long/Namespace/ServiceCollectionName/